# How to retrieve a testdisk disk image file from an XFS partition?

Tags: debian, data-recovery, disk-image, xfs, testdisk

#### The previous situation

I had a problem many years ago with an HDD (with a Windows installation and two usual partitions - the boot one and the NTFS one containing the system and the data) with which I ended up making a disk image thanks to `testdisk`. This disk image is trivially named `image.dd` (I was learning and since it was crucial to me to retrieve at some point the data, I followed thoroughly the tutorial to the point where I used the exact name specified in the testdisk turorial). That file is about 250GB and was moved to several disks and devices along the following years. It ended up on a NAS, on an XFS partition. **At some point, one of my brother deleted it, because it took too much space.**

#### The current situation

The NAS ended up dying but its unique HDD is not. I am accessing the disk through a USB/SATA dock and I am trying to use `photorec` to retrieve files. I am surprisingly able to retrieve really old deleted files I am not really interested in but the only file I would really retrieve is the previous `image.dd` file I previously mentioned. Since there was not a lot of writing on the disk, I am confident that, at least partially, the file is still there (which would explains why the NAS died way before the HDD) since `photorec` is able to retrieve files from the XFS partition where the files were stored.

This last point was a surprise and I thought the adventure would just stop there, and at least I know that `photorec` is able to retrieve files from XFS partitions. Especially since after seeing that `testdisk` does not provide you with the option to find the deleted files on an XFS partition.

Now, what I am concerned about is, even if the file could be retrieved, I will not be able to retrieve the disk image file `image.dd` because `photorec` has a precise list of files that can be retrieved. I am guessing that `photorec` uses the header and/or the extension of files to retrieve them and I do not know what I should expect from a `testdisk` disk file as a header or if there is any nor if a the weird `.dd` extension I put could be an advantage or a drawback here.

I know that I could [add my own signature/extension to `photorec`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Add_your_own_extension_to_PhotoRec) but, since I do not know what to expect from a `testdisk` disk image file, it seems like a bit of a dead end.

So, my question would be: **is there anything to try to retrieve that specific file in this situation?**

P.S.: I tried to simplify the situation because it would be even more tedious to follow what happened but I hope I have been clear enough. Let me know in the comments what details I could provide to make it clearer.

P.S.S.: I am running Debian 9.9 on the machine trying to retrieve the data.

Comment: so... the filesystem is damaged somehow? `photorec` would likely also recover files from within the image itself (if it's not compressed or encrypted).

Comment: Sorry I forgot the most obvious thing to say. The disk image file I would like to retrieve has been deleted. I changed it in the answer. The XFS filesystem is totally fine, the only thing that died was the NAS itself (one-drive bay small NAS). For now, it is my best chance to retrieve this file but it has been on a different NAS and deleted by one of my brother as well there... I would need to try on that different one if it does not work on the current HDD.